# Percentage increase/decrease of a group of data in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like:

```
|| date || bytes || table ||
```

I need to work out the yearly growth (percentage increase or decrease) for all tables based on size and year. I have a query which mostly gives me the information I want, which I can parse and use external tools to produce the data that is required, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to perform the percentage increase calculations directly in the query?

This is how my query looks right now:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(date) AS YEAR,
    table,
    SUM(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS total
FROM
    insertions
GROUP BY table, YEAR (date)
ORDER BY    date;
```

Is it possible to have a field that has the percentage increase/decrease for the current table relative to the previous year?

Sample output:

```
| date | bytes | table      | 
| 2015 | 100   | accounting |
| 2016 | 150   | accounting |
| 2015 | 1     | it         |
| 2016 | 100   | it         |
```

With the percentage increase, it should instead look like:

```
| date | bytes | table      | percentage 
| 2015 | 100   | accounting | 0
| 2016 | 150   | accounting | 50
| 2015 | 1     | it         | 0
| 2016 | 100   | it         | 9900
```

Comment: Can you please  show some sample data and expected result

Comment: Does MySQL execute that query?!?

Comment: Yes, it does execute and produce the grouping per table/per year correctly.

Comment: To be honest, this is easiest to accomplish at a higher layer of your application—because MySQL does not support analytic functions, the only way to achieve it within the database would be to use hacks involving user variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for doing this uses variables to get the previous value:

```
  SELECT year, table, total,
         (@prev := (case when (@new_prev := @prev) = null
                         then 'never go here'
                         when @t = table
                         then if(@prev := total, @new_prev, @new_prev)
                         when @t := table
                         then if(@prev := total, NULL, NULL)
                    end)
         ) as prev_total
  FROM (SELECT YEAR(date) AS YEAR, table, SUM(bytes) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS total
        FROM insertions i
        GROUP BY table, YEAR (date)
       ) yt CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT @t := '', @prev := -1) params
  ORDER BY table, date
```

The rest is just arithmetic to use a subquery to get the difference.

Note:  This is particularly challenging because all the formulas using variables have to be in a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so you cannot safely use variables in multiple expressions (with assignments).